# Selenium Webdriver Actions - can I replace deprecated pause method with something else?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I noticed that pause() method is deprecated in Selenium Webdriver (http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html)

Pause is indeed somehow bad practice, but then how can I simulate the following scenario? :

- go to a webpage
- select text rendered as image (DRM reasons, with an extra logical layer over it)
- do something...

The problem here is that if I do a moveToElement().clickAndHold().moveToOffset() what I get is actually a "swype", there is such a feature on the page. What I want is click and hold on the element, a bit of a pause simulating human behavior (100 ms is more than enough). I don't see another way of doing it without pause(). Is there any?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: At Google Code, [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7424) exists for this (perhaps by the same person as this question?), as well as [a new implementation suggestion](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7646)

Comment: Yes Geert, I forgot about that one and it seems Google Code does not send updates all the time. Closing the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what language bindings you use to write your WebDriver tests but in C# or Java you could just use Thread.Sleep(100). I'm sure there is an equivalent in all other languages. Or I think WebDriverWait laterBy(long durationInMillis) would do the same as the Thread.Sleep.

I personally would prefer to perform the test as fast as possible so I have a custom wait method that waits for the element to be present and visible before allowing the next step.

In the example below the thread.sleep is inserted between the sendKeys and assertEquals steps.

```
      @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.uk/";
  }

  @Test
  public void test1() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("selenium");
    thread.sleep(100);
    assertEquals("selenium", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("cite._Pd > b")).getText());
  }
```

Comment: It's java. How would you stick a Thread.sleep() into an Actions chain? Looks like my explanation was not great, I was mentioning that without the pause after clickAndHold() the action does a "swype" on the page. It has really nothing to do with synchronization, waiting for element to be present, etc.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer I gave.

Comment: Again, this is a completely different thing, I was talking about the Actions API. In you example, I wouldn't use the sleep, just because you cannot be 100% sure that 100 ms is always enough. I would instead use WebDriverWait. But unfortunately this does not apply to my scenario. I am talking about selecting text, an action which triggers an event in our app.